# Golang: map with multiple values per key

Tags: arrays, go

```
 func ParseportsFromFile(file string) (map[string]string, error) {
            buf, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            ret := [make(map[string]string)]
            rows := strings.Split(string(buf), "\n")
            for _, row := range rows {
                kvs := strings.SplitN(row, "=", 2)
                if len(kvs) == 2 {
                    ret[strings.TrimSpace(kvs[0])] = strings.TrimSpace(kvs[1])
                }
            }
            return ret, nil
        }
```

This function allows me to read a file like that :

```
user1=123 
user1=321 
user2=124
```

However, the data return is

```
map[user1:321 user2:124]
```

So that mean user1=123 has been overwritten with user1=321
How to avoid that ?
How to create an array like
map[user1:[123,321], user2: 124]
to avoid an item to overwrite another ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since go is strongly typed, it would be easier to make it right away a map of slices. See the [http.Header](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Header) type, for example. They had the same problem to solve when designing it.

In your case, this could look something like this:

```golang
result := make(map[string][]string)

for _, row := range rows {
    parts := strings.Split(row, "=")
    key := parts[0]
    value := parts[1]
    result[key] = append(result[key], value)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/5uRH-aQmATR

Otherwise, you need to use `interface{}` (any) so you can have both, `string` and `[]string`, but the logic to get that done would be more complex, and using it would be also more complex since you always need to check what it is and do type assertion and so on. After all, I would not recommend it.